# Proof Validation 2

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Suppose lim$_{x\to 0} \frac{\phi(x)}{\psi(x)} = 1$ where $\psi(x) > 0$. Let $\alpha_{mn}$ be a doubly index sequence with property that $\alpha_{mn}$ tends to $0$ uniformly in m as n tends to $\infty$. That is to say, for every given $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $N = N(\epsilon) > 0$ such that if $n > N$, and for any m we have $|\alpha_{mn}| < \epsilon$. Suppose the limit lim$_{n\to\infty} [\psi(\alpha_{1n}) + ... \psi(\alpha_{nn})]$ exists and set it equal to $\beta$. Show that

$$lim_{n\to\infty} [\phi(\alpha_{1n}) + ... + \phi(\alpha_{nn})] = \beta$$

Since lim$_{x\to 0} \frac{\phi(x)}{\psi(x)} = 1$, there exists an M such that if $|x|<M$,  $|\frac{\phi(x)}{\psi(x)} - 1| < \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$. Choose $\epsilon = \frac{1}{n}$ for some arbitrarily large n. Then we have:

$$|\frac{\phi(x)}{\psi(x)} - 1| < \frac{1}{n}\implies -\frac{1}{n} < \frac{\phi(x)}{\psi(x)} < \frac{1}{n}\implies -\frac{1}{n}\psi(x) < \phi(x) - \psi(x) <\frac{1}{n}\psi(x)$$

and

$$-\frac{1}{n}(\psi(\alpha_{1n}) + ... \psi(\alpha_{nn})) <[\phi(\alpha_{1n}) + ... + \phi(\alpha_{nn})] - [\psi(\alpha_{1n}) + ... \psi(\alpha_{nn})] < \frac{1}{n}(\psi(\alpha_{1n}) + ... \psi(\alpha_{nn}))$$

Since limit lim$_{n\to\infty} [\psi(\alpha_{1n}) + ... \psi(\alpha(nn)] = \beta$ and $\alpha_{mn}$ tends to $0$ uniformly in m as n tends to $\infty$, we have as $n \geq K$, if 
$|\alpha_{mn}| < N$. 
$$lim_{\alpha_{nn\to0}} [\psi(\alpha_{1n}) + ... \psi(\alpha_{nn})] = \beta$$

Choose P = min{M,N}. Then, if $|x|<P$ and $|\alpha_{mn}| < P$, and let $n \to \infty$,

$$0 < -\frac{1}{n}(\psi(\alpha_{1n}) + ... \psi(\alpha_{nn})) <[\phi(\alpha_{1n}) + ... + \phi(\alpha_{nn})]-[\psi(\alpha_{1n}) + ... \psi(\alpha_{nn})] < \frac{1}{n}(\psi(\alpha_{1n}) + ... \psi(\alpha_{nn})) < 0$$

*Note that we can let $n \to \infty$ because the larger the value of n, the smaller the value of P, which means $|x|<P$ and $|\alpha_{mn}| < P$ will still hold.

By squeeze theorem,

$$\lim_{\alpha_{mn} \to 0}[\phi(\alpha_{1n}) + ... + \phi(\alpha_{nn})]-[\psi(\alpha_{1n}) + ... \psi(\alpha_{nn})]$$ exists and is equal to 0.

Therefore, we can conclude that $lim_{n\to\infty} [\phi(\alpha_{1n}) + ... + \phi(\alpha_{nn})] = \beta$.

Answer (score 1):

(I'm doing this as an answer, rather than a comment because of its length.)

In these kind of limit problems,
when you have
$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n a_k = \alpha
$
and
$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} = 1
$,
there is an final part 
where $|\frac{a_n}{b_n}-1| < \epsilon$
for $n > n_0(\epsilon)$
and the initial part where this is not necessarily true.

The proof that the desired limit is
also $\alpha$
is done by considering the two parts of
the sum
(one when $|...|<\epsilon$
and one when not),
and showing that the part when
$| ...| > \epsilon$
becomes as small as you want for
large enough $n$,
so only the part where
$|...| < \epsilon$
matters.

Comment: I know the idea but I just can't figure out how.